# delay in applying Antd CSS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd

When I reload the page in Next.js when using Antd CSS, there is a delay in applying CSS styles. Immediately after the page is reloaded, there is a noticeable delay and the content looks very crooked. How can I solve this problem?

Most likely it's because of SSR, but I couldn't solve this problem.

- next.js: 13
- antd: 5

Answer (score 0):

You can create a context that will be in the root of your app and showing only a load then after all computation, loading, data fetching... has completed you just set to hide the load.

Here's a quick example:

```
// mycontext.ts

import React, {
  useState,
  createContext,
  useMemo,
  useContext
} from 'react'
import {
  Spin
} from 'antd'

type ContextType = {
  loading: boolean
  setLoading: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
}

const MyContext = createContext( {} as ContextType )

export function ContextProvider({children}) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true)

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider
      value={useMemo(() => ({
        loading, setLoading
      }), [loading])}
    >
      <Spin spinning={loading}>
        {children}
      </Spin>
    </MyContext.Provider>
  )
}

export function useMyContext {
  return useContext(MyContext)
}
```

Now in your app entry point (_app.tsx):

```
import {ContextProvider} from 'path/to/context'
import {
  App,
  ConfigProvider
} from 'antd'

function _app({
  Component,
  pageProps
}: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ConfigProvider
        locale={ ... }
        theme={ ... }
    >
      <App>
        <ContextProvider { ...pageProps }>
          <Component { ...pageProps } />
        </ContextProvider>
      </App>
    </ConfigProvider>
  )
}
```

Now inside your components you have control on loading of this context too if you want to show load while do something else:

```
// anycomponent.tsx

import {useMyContext} from 'path/to/context'

function MyComponent() {
  const {loading, setLoading} = useMyContext()

  ....
}
```

Comment: it's a good idea, but I've never seen a loader needed to load styles. It seems to me that the problem is in the server render and the antd library.

Comment: I use nextjs with antd in my app but I'm not using SSR so I don't know how it works in this case but my app also have a little delay (about 1sec) to set styles (I suppose this is because of dynamic dark/light theme) so the best way I've found to hide/mask this style delay was using a loader

Answer (score 0):

create a file like that.

```
"use client";

import { StyleProvider, createCache, extractStyle } from "@ant-design/cssinjs";
import { useServerInsertedHTML } from "next/navigation";
import React from "react";
const StyledComponentsRegistry = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const cache = createCache();
  useServerInsertedHTML(() => <style id="antd" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: extractStyle(cache, true) }} />);

  const render = <>{children}</>;

  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    return render;
  }

  return (
    <StyleProvider hashPriority="high" cache={cache}>
      {children}
    </StyleProvider>
  );
};

export default StyledComponentsRegistry;
```

and wrap it in main layout file

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className="bg-gray-200">
                  <StyledComponentsRegistry>{children}</StyledComponentsRegistry>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

it worked for me. if it is not working try to update packages

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your ***_document.tsx*** file

```js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: App => props => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        })

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      }
    } finally {
      sheet.seal()
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

Refer to this link [Link](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-next)